# How to use SysInternal Handle to identify which object in the code has locked the "Test File.pdf" file

Tags: c#, process-explorer

I need to know how I can use Handle to identify which object in the code has locked the pdf file.

I  generated pdf file with crystal reports in the background, email pdf to the recipients and then wanted to delete the file but was keep getting this message

```
 System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file &#39;c:\test\First Report for test.pdf&#39; because it is being used by another process.
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
```

I disposed `ReportDocument` & `SmtpClient` object but that did not help, then I tried ProcessExplorer and command line handle with following command

```
C:\Users\demouser\SysinternalsSuite> handle test\First Report for test.pdf
```

and that did not help either. I examined the code again and resolved the issue by calling dispose method of `MailMessage`

So I am wondering if handle could be used in the first instance to identify locking object in the code.

Comment: Objects don't impose handles on files; processes do. I don't think you can find what object inside your code translates to what handle.

Comment: Either use a filename without blanks or enclose the filename in double quotes "....". It might be more convenient to use the find/handle menu of ProcessExplorer.

Comment: @AxelKemper. when i typed First Report for test.pdf in the ProcessExplorer search it returned 0 matching item.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel. so the only way to resolve the locking issue was to examine the not disposed object which i did at the end.